# Print contents of GAC to file

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, gac

I am trying to provide VIEW access to the GAC. Ideally what I want is for them to see the contents of the assembly folder as you see it in Windows explorer (ie with version number and so on).  I am happy to list this in a text file and provide that to them. But I can't figure out how to do this.

Note: this is a server is not a development machine, so we do not have the SDK installed to use gacutil. Also, I don't to remove/install items in the GAC. Just to view it, so gacutil is a little to powerful in that respect.

Comment: The customized folder view of the v2.0 GAC in c:\windows\assembly is provided by a shell extension.  It is outdated, the v4.0 GAC in c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly does not use the shell extension anymore.  You see the content of the directory as-is.  Lots of sub-directories so nothing that is easily printable.  You'd have to write a program to iterate the GAC directories yourself.  Or just not bother, that printout isn't very useful when it gets outdated and just looking at the GAC directly is always possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of an free and open source PowerShell module called [PowerShell GAC](http://powershellgac.codeplex.com/) that could help you. The following will print out the contents of the GAC.

```
Get-GacAssembly | Out-Printer
```

You can also [filter the assemblies on name](http://powershellgac.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Get-GacAssembly&referringTitle=Home) for example, or have it sent to a file with Out-File, or show other columns like the [file version](http://powershellgac.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FileVersion%20Table%20View&referringTitle=Home) besides the assembly version.